# Why is Linq to Entity Select Method flip flopping projected lists properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm have the strangest behavior with linq to entity / Json / MVC.net 4

I have this bit of code, and for some odd reason, every other list's property order is reversed.

```cs
var output = db.FooBar.Where(a => a.lookupFoo == bar)
                      .Select(a => new List<double>{
                                     //value's are the same per row 
                                     //for demonstration sake.
                          a.fooBarA,  //Always 12.34
                          a.fooBarB,  //Always 12.34
                          a.fooBarC,  //Always 0
                          a.fooBarD  //Always 0 //lazy casting to double from int
                      });
return Json(new {output});
```

output looks like so:

```
{
  "output": [
    [12.34, 12.34, 0,     0], 
    [0,     0,     12.34, 12.34], 
    [12.34, 12.34, 0,     0],
    [0,     0,     12.34, 12.34]
  ]
};
```

I've managed to work around it by putting a `toList()` between the Where, and Select, but I'd still like to know why this behavior is happening.

More info:
EF 4.4 (tt generated Context), SQL Server 2008r2 express .NET 4.0, MVC 3.0, Vanilla System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult, table consists of a int primary key, floats for values excluding last one which is a int

Comment: In your example, it's not order of objects that is flipped. Apparently values of properties on single object are switched(?). a.fooBarA holds value of a.fooBarC. Can you make example (or description) clear?

Comment: I was assuming that (being there are no key's for the output) that that the actual properties were being switched not necessarily the values. P.S. Did you know your reputation is Evil(666) at the moment @Nenad

Comment: Properties cannot be switched by Linq, so problem must be something else that is not obvious from your example. Evil, yes. That's why I stopped writing answers, only comments. :P

Comment: Which json library are you using? Well, regardless, it's obviously something someone does that only gets exposed when lazy evaluation is performed. I suppose the only way to properly answer the question would be to set up symbols properly and step through the code until you figure it out... Alternatively there might be something else you're omitting - is it a vanilla EF setup or did you customize anything? I might give it a shot at reproducing it...

Comment: Nope, can't reproduce using MVC4 and default Json serializer.

Comment: I'll see if i can give a better (reproducable) example. Off the top of my head, I think its the built in Json Serializer though it may be json.net, will check when I get into work tomorrow, the project did start of as mvc.net 3.5, and was later switched to 4.0. And I'm using vanilla EF, with "database first" generated models.

Comment: woops .net 4.0, and mvc 3.0

Comment: Have you verified that the data in the data source is correct?

Comment: @WillFM, The code in your sample isn't valid (i.e. no commas between the `a.fooBarX` items). Is it possible that something else was lost in the preparation of the question?

Comment: @William Yes, the data is correct.

Comment: @Simon McKenzie, was writing pseudo code based on some production code that is privately maintained by my employer, missed out on the commas sorry about that. Only other things I left out is were using SQL Server 2008r2 Express. I haven't looked into this lately, but my next step will probably be to debug the SQL the EF generates and see if its happening in the query, or in EF Mapper.

Comment: Seems like another outer variable trap
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416758/outer-variable-trap

Comment: Unless your JSON library has a bug, it should *never* be rearranging the order of values in a JSON array. So either your JSON library is buggy (doubtful) or your claims about the values "Always" being some value are false.

Comment: To debug this further, what's the result if you change the `.Select` to `.Select(a => new List<double>{1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0})`?

Comment: And similarly try `.Select(a => new List<bool>{a.fooBarA==12.34,a.fooBarB==12.34,a.fooBarC==0.0,a.fooBarD==0})`.

Comment: @Onur That could be a possibility, in which case, if I change my delegate to another name e.g. f instead of e, that might fix the issue, I've long since moved passed the issue (I use the toList method as mentioned in my answer, I was really just trying to clarify why this behavior happened otherwise). Next time I get the chance I'll look at the code, and see if making a new delegate will generate the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var output = db.FooBar.Where(a => a.lookupFoo == bar)
                  .Select(a => new List<double>{
                                 //value's are the same per row 
                                 //for demonstration sake.
                      a.fooBarA,  //Always 12.34
                      a.fooBarB,  //Always 12.34
                      a.fooBarC,  //Always 0
                      a.fooBarD  //Always 0 //lazy casting to double from int
                  }).toList();
return Json(output);
```

On your way output just context the generated script for get data
may be it Excute manytime in size Json()

Answer (score 0):

Add a .ToArray and see what you get. Remember that the linq (Select.. exc) is only executed when IEnumerator is called.

I think if you add ToArray, the result would be the same each time, and consistent.

Hope that helps.