# Passing Parameter to Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Im running a c# code with background worker. Im impelmenting it by having a foreach loop and inside the loop im passing the foreach variable as parameter for the Backgroundworker. But the problem is that whenever i run the code only single random value, most probably the last row in the gridview is passed as parameter. The code is as here

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.DoWork += delegate
    {
        data = dataGridView3.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        rowindex = row.Index;
        data1 = ros[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    };

    worker.RunWorkerAync();
}
```

Comment: This is explained at [Eric Lippers blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

try by sending parameter as `row`

```
worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    DataGridViewRow  dgr = (DataGridViewRow)args.Argument;
    data = dataGridView3.Rows[dgr.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    rowindex = dgr.Index;
    data1 = dgr[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
};

worker.RunWorkerAsync(row);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Damith's answer, you can also capture the foreach variable in the local scope.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewRow copy = row; // captured!
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.DoWork += delegate
    {
        data = dataGridView3.Rows[copy.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        rowindex = copy.Index;
        data1 = copy[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    };

    worker.RunWorkerAync();
}
```

This is because the `row` variable is bound to a different value in each iteration, and as such you get the value of row  at the last iteration.

This is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416758/outer-variable-trap) as well as in [Eric Lipperts blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the line

```
data = dataGridView3.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

can be modified to:

```
data = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

because it sort of defeats the entire purpose of the `foreach` statement.
Also, the following line seems to have a typo in it:

```
data1 = ros[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

I'm not sure what you intend `data1` to contain, but you may want to consider simply passing your `BackgroundWorker` the `DataGridView row` variable from your `foreach` statement, and then pull the necessary data out inside the `DoWork` method.