# Puppet: all custom facts gets all results

Tags: ruby, puppet, facter

I´m trying to work out a way in Puppet to get the current zpool capacity numbers for my FreeBSD storage servers, storing them in custom facts and to generate alert if capacity reaches a "too high" level. Closest match to my problem that I´ve found so far is:
[Returning multiple custom facts with puppet Facter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127545/returning-multiple-custom-facts-with-puppet-facter)

That pointed me to this solution:

```
operatingsystem = Facter.value('operatingsystem')
case operatingsystem
when "FreeBSD"

  present_zpools = IO.popen('zpool list -H -o name').read.chomp            
  if ! present_zpools.empty?

    Facter.add(:zpools) do
      setcode do
        zpools = IO.popen('for i in $(zpool list -H -o name); do echo $i; done').read.chomp.split("\n")
      end
    end

    def addZpoolCapacityFact(zpool)
      zpool_capacity = IO.popen('zpool get -H -o value capacity #{zpool}').read.tr('%','').chomp

      Facter.add("capacity_" + zpool) do
        setcode do
          zpool_capacity
        end
      end

    end                                                                                                    

    zpools = Facter.value(:zpools)
    zpools.each do |zpool|
      addZpoolCapacityFact(zpool)
    end

  end

end
```

But doesn´t quite produce the result I was expecting, e.g:

```
capacity_pool1: 10 30
capacity_pool2: 10 30
```

When I was really expecting:

```
capacity_pool1: 10
capacity_pool2: 30
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OK, solved!

The problem was using IO.popen two times in same script, even though I tried nil'ing the variables, the first split function applied to variable 'zpools' was also run on 'zpool_capacity', I think, which made the result look like:

```
"capacity_pool1":"10\n12","capacity_pool2":"10\n12"
```

Notice the '\n' between the numbers? I´m sure there´s a Ruby way to be able to use IO.popen multiple times but I don´t know how, so I just changed the commands to execute with plain backticks (`) and here´s the working code:

```
operatingsystem = Facter.value('operatingsystem')
case operatingsystem
when "FreeBSD"

  present_zpools = `zpool list -H -o name`.chomp
  if ! present_zpools.empty?

    Facter.add(:zpools) do
      setcode do
        zpools = `for i in $(zpool list -H -o name); do echo $i; done`.chomp.split("\n")
      end
    end

    def addZpoolCapacityFact(zpool)
      zpool_capacity = `zpool get -H -o value capacity #{zpool}`.tr('%','').chomp

      Facter.add(zpool + "_capacity") do
        setcode do
          zpool_capacity
        end
      end

    end                                                                                                    

    zpools = Facter.value(:zpools)
    zpools.each do |zpool|
      addZpoolCapacityFact(zpool)
    end

  end

end
```

Now result looks like I´d expect:

```
pool1_capacity: 10
pool2_capacity: 30
```