# Why is var modified in closure not retaining value

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, closures

From what I understand about closures - based on for example [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/11225) and [Closures](http://javascript.info/tutorial/closures), variables declared in a closure's outer (or parent) function can be used and modified in the closure so that after the closure finishes, the variable in the outer function has the value it was last assigned in the closure.

Perhaps my understanding is incorrect, or there is something else going on in the code below that I can't quite fathom yet. <sup>1</sup>

```
function showBoards(boards, outputTarget) {
  $.each(boards, function (index, board) {
    var brd = $("<p><span class='badge' style='background:" 
      + board.prefs.backgroundColor + ";'>" 
      + ((board.starred) ? "*" : " ") + "</span> " 
      + board.name + "</p>");
    $(outputTarget).append(brd);
  });
}

function loadTheLot() {
  var boards = [];
  Trello.get('/members/me/boards?filter=open&fields=name,url,prefs,starred')
    .success(function (response) { 
      $.extend(boards, response);
      showBoards(boards, "#boards");
      })
    .error(function () { console.log("Failed to load boards.");})
    ;
  //showBoards(boards, "#boards");
  loadCardsInList("To do this week", "#todocards");
  loadCardsInList("Waiting for response", "#waitingcards");
}
```

The `extend` works as expected. When I call the `showBoards` function inside the "success" closure, the output on my page neatly lists the boards that were retrieved.

When I call the `showBoards` function in the closure's outer function (as the commented line shows), the page doesn't show any boards at all.

Of course the `$.each` is a loop in disguise, but it is inside the a function called from the closure. As far as I understand it, there doesn't seem to be anything like the "closures in a for loop gotcha" (Aka [Outer Variable Trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3416792/11225) going on here.

**Question**: Why is the `boards` variable declared in `loadTheLot` empty again after the `Trello.Get` statement.

By the way, the reason I need the boards array outside the whole `Trello.get` stuff is because I want to pass the boards to the loadCardsInList function so the cards can show the board names instead of an ugly identifier.

By the way I used the `get().success().error()` style because someone with what appeared a similar issue was adviced to use a "post-ajax callback" to ensure everything had finished. The style I used before had the success and error closures as the second and third parameter of the `Trello.get` call.

<sup>1</sup> I'm not exactly new to programming, but my javascript skills are very much nascent.

Comment: The commented out line fires before the asynchronous success callback function has even run.

Comment: $.extend(boards, response); <-- why? That does not make sense on why you need to do that.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, I sort of thought it might be something like that, but couldn't see it while debugging. Got lost in the trenches so to speak... And I didn't think to search with asynchronous ... (It's a bit late here...)