# kendo tabstrip ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I use the kendo tab strip and try to show a tab for each item of a model collection.

```
@if (Model.Entities.Count > 1)
{
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("tabstrip")
        .Items(items =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Entities.Count; i++)
            {
                items.Add()
                    .Text(Model.Entities[i].Name)
                    .Selected(i == 0)
                    .Content(@<div>
                                @Model.Entities[i].Name //causes exception
                            </div>
                            );
            }
        })
    )
}
```

The markup in the tab content (@Model.Entities[i].Name) causes an exception.

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or how to implement it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encountered the [outer variable trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416758/outer-variable-trap).

This worked for me:

```
@if (Model.Entities.Count > 1)
{
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("tabstrip")
        .Items(items =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Entities.Count; i++)
            {
                var i1 = i;
                items.Add()
                    .Text(Model.Entities[i].Name)
                    .Selected(i == 0)
                    .Content(@<div>
                                @Model.Entities[i1].Name 
                            </div>
                            );
            }
        })
    )
}
```