# Why dictionary does not return the correct value of the key?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I store keys and values in the dictionary, But the problem is that the dictionary retrieve wrong value for the specific key. it retrieves the last stored value in the array[] variable
I need a help for solving this problem

```
  public String Encrypt(String PlainText, String Key)
        {
            Dictionary<int, byte[]> PlainToCipherDic = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
            String EncryptedText = "";           

            for (int i = 0; i < PlainBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                    int XoredInt = Convert.ToInt32(PlainBytes[i]);
                    if (!PlainToCipherDic.ContainsKey(XoredInt))
                  {                   
                    int PlainInteger = XoredInt;               

                    EncryptedBytes[i * 2] = PlainBytes[i];                   
                    EncryptedBytes[i * 2 + 1] = Mapping[i];                   
                   array[0] = EncryptedBytes[i * 2];
                   array[1] = EncryptedBytes[i * 2+1];
                   PlainToCipherDic.Add(XoredInt, array);

                }
                else
                {
                   byte[] value;
                  PlainToCipherDic.TryGetValue(XoredInt, out value);
                  EncryptedBytes[i * 2] = value[0];
                 EncryptedBytes[i * 2+1] = value[1];

                }

            }
               EncryptedText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(EncryptedBytes);

                //Console.WriteLine("PlainToCipherDic : " + PlainToCipherDic.TryGetValue(XoredBytes, out EncryptedBytes));
            return EncryptedText;
            }
```

Comment: make sure `array` is a new array every time you are adding it to `PlainToCipherDic`, and not the same one over and over again.  Your code snippet is not complete so I can't be sure that is the problem

Comment: You need to exit your loop when the value is found.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "it retrieves the last stored value in the array[0] array[1] variable". That's not a proper name for a variable. Try this: which line of code is producing the result you don't expect? What result is it producing? What result did you expect and why?

Comment: That is mostly since you are storing the reference to an array, this is not storing value, now when you fetch it will provide current value in the array, which might have been updated. In your code snippet, I just see 1 update to array in the if logic

Comment: Where and how is array declared?  You're most probably encountering the outer variable trap... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416758/outer-variable-trap

Comment: Yes Mick, you are right when I replaced array inside loop it returned the right answer , Really I appreciate your efforts. and very thanks for all who replied me

Answer (score 3):

You continue your loop regardless. You need to exit the loop when found.