# ASP.NET MVC - get list of objects from query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm passed a list of parameters. Such as "Name", "Id", "Type".  There will be an many of these in url, like so:

```
"Name=blah1,Id=231,Type=blah1;Name=blah2,Id=2221,Type=blah1;Name=blah3,Id=45411,Type=blah3;"
```

I wonder if there is a way to map these query parameters to a List of objects. So, I can create an object:

MyTestObject {Name;Id;Type}  and can say in my controller

```
Index(IList<MyTestObject> params)
```

params will be filled in with data from query string.

Something that is similar to http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: Have you tried implementing what was suggested in that link? I've used it before and it fulfilled my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ASP.NET MVC could automatically bind collections to action params, but you need to pass your params as a from values, moreover, it is looks like to many params you going pass in query string. Have look at this one http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-model-binding-for-a-collection.aspx

Basically what you need to do:

1) Create your class which would contain your params

```
public class MyParam 
{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}

 //do all the rest
}
```

2) Create model which you would pass to your view

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  IList<MyParam> MyParams {get; set;}
}
```

3) Create your collection in your `[HttpGet]` action and pass that to your view:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
   MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
   model.MyParams = CreateMyParamsCollection();

   return View(model);
}
```

4) Iterate your collection in the view

```
@model MyViewModel

@{int index = 0;}

@foreach (MyParam detail in Model.MyParams)
{
  @Html.TextBox("MyParams[" + index.ToString() + "].Id", detail.Id)
  @Html.TextBox("MyParams[" + index.ToString() + "].Name", detail.Name)

  index++;
}
```

5) Than on your `[HttpPost]` action you may catch your params in collection

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Index(IList<MyParam> model)
```

**P.S**

Moreover, if you want to get all your form params in controller you may simple go like that:

```
[HttpPost]    
public virtual ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739211/asp-net-mvc-get-list-of-objects-from-query-string/6748667#6748667

Answer (score 5):

I actually followed advice in the [article by Mr. Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)  I created a class with all of the parameters as public properties. Then I had a view take a list of objects of that type. If the query parameter names follow a certain pattern (prepended by index) then I get a list of my object automatically populated and I don't have to do any manual parsing at all. This is the simplest solution for me.

Example:

query param object:

```
public class QueryParams
{
   public string Id,
   public string Name,
   public string Type
}
```

in controller method:

```
public ActionResult Index(IList<QueryParams> queryData)
```

then I make sure that query string is formated in the following way(prepended by index):

> http://localhost/myapp/?[0].id=123&[0].Name=blah&[0].Type=Person&[1].Id=345&[1].Name=example&[1].Type=Stuff

In my controller, queryData list parameter will contain two objects populated with correct data.

Comment: This is actually pretty simple and it does the work!

Comment: I wish that the format was better documented - it still works with .NET5 but here's the first place I found (after a few days digging) how to pass along arrays and complex types/objects. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4):

You can you a values provider, and it will populate values from the querystring into a single object.  This is what you would do if you're not going to create a View Model.

Transform the QueryString into a FormCollection via:

```
var GetCollection = new FormCollection( Request.QueryString );
```

Comment: Just drop it into your controller.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a **custom model binder**, that works off the `Request.QueryString` collection, rather than the regular `FormCollection`.

E.g:

```
public class MyTestObjectModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder 
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) 
    {
        var qs = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;                  
        return new MyTestObject
        {
           Name = qs["Name"],
           Id = qs["Id"],
           // etc, etc
        };
    }
}
```

Then setup your `[HttpGet]` action accordingly:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(MyTestObjectModelBinder))]MyTestObject m) {

}
```

You could also register it globally if you like, e.g on `Application_Start()` :

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyTestObject), new MyTestObjectModelBinder());
```

Then you just need the model on your action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(MyTestObject m) {

}
```

**Having said all of this**, if you've got this many parameters, one must ask where do these parameters come from? Most likely a form on another page.

In which case, this should be a `[HttpPost]` action, with the parameters in the form collection, then the regular MVC model binding will take care of the above code for you.

Comment: +1 I was thinking a custom model binder too, but too lazy to write my own answer.

Comment: @RPM1984  Can I do the following?  It seems to be a simple solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739211/asp-net-mvc-get-list-of-objects-from-query-string/6748667#6748667

Comment: @dev.e.loper - if it works for you, sure. However it might make maintenance difficult, since it's not immediately clear how the binding it working, and you have to maintain two places (generation of URL, and the model convention). Custom model binders make it explicit, and a single place to maintain the binding. However, whatever works for you.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, I was looking for a way to enumerate through the QueryString name-value collection, and this is what I came up with:

```
        var qry =HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

        if (qry.HasKeys())
        {
            foreach (var key in qry)
            {
                if(key != null)
                    var str= String.Format("Key:{0}, value:{1} ", key, qry.Get(key.ToString()));
            }
        }
```

This code will give you all the names and their values in the QueryString.

Comment: You can't use the str variable declaration in a for each statement. The str variable declaration should be before the for each statement.

Comment: Does not really matter. See the following comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884906/declaring-a-variable-inside-or-outside-an-foreach-loop-which-is-faster-better#comment1785311_1884957

Comment: The problem is when the code is compiled in Visual Studio 2013 we get a compiler error if you declare the variable in a for each loop. Maybe there is some configuration that could prevent this, but by default we get that compiler error.