# MVC 3.0 ModelBinder bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key) returns null when binding in a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelbinder

I am new using custom ModelBinders, I have been looking around and I couldn't find any post related to this specific case.

I have an entity like:

```
 public class DynamicData
    {
       public IList<DynamicDataItem> DynamicDataItems{get;set;}
    }
```

In the View i bind it like follows:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DynamicDataItems);
```

I have special information in the class DynamicDataItems, that I would like to retrieve in a specific way, so I created my own Model Binder.

```
public class DynamicDataItemBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var key = bindingContext.ModelName;
            var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
                .GetValue(key);

            if (valueProviderResult == null ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueProviderResult
                    .AttemptedValue))
            {
                return null;
            }

            //Here retrieve my own Information

            return DynamicDataItem;
        }
    }
```

The bindingContext.ModelName contains "DynamicDataItem[0]".

If I do bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(key), it returns true, but when I do GetValue(key), it returns null.
If I inspect what the ValueProvider contains, I see that there is several items with their Key Starting in "DynamicDataItem[0]".
How Am I supossed to retrieve the information from all the fields for the Item that is being binded currently ("DynamicDataItem[0]")? 
Should I retrieve them all one by one?
Like this:

```
 var result1= bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("DynamicDataItem[0].Id");
 var result2= bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("DynamicDataItem[0].Name");
```

I will greatly appreciate any guidance you can give me with this.

Comment: I suggest you that visit [this link][1]. I think it's useful for your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25902872/1817640

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old post but I have the same problem and my solution was to use bindingContext.ModelName:

```
ValueProviderResult result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name);
if(result == null)
    result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + "." + propertyDescriptor.Name);
```

Comment: Where did propertyDescriptor come from?

Comment: @onefootswill, I can not remember now but I think it comes from the method: BindProperty(ControllerContext, ModelBindingContext, PropertyDescriptor) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.bindproperty?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: Thanks @vangi I realized at some point that this question was dealing with an old version of the API. I solved my problem without needing to get the value from the `ValueProvider`. Cheers.

Comment: @onefootswill How did you get the list items then?

Comment: @bzmid If your are creating a modelbinder for a list of some kind, I'd take a look at the [CollectionModelBinder source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/CollectionModelBinder.cs), which will probably be doing what you need

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that your are trying to bind an object of type `DynamicDataItem` to an input. Since `DynamicDataItem` isn't a string or some other primitive type, there is no straightforward way for the binder to figure out what to do with your input and it returns null.

Assuming the class `DynamicDataItem` has properties of it's own what you want to do is provide editors for each property of a `DynamicDataItem`. If all you are trying to do is pass a model with a bound collection of child objects from a view, you don't even need a custom model binder. What I think you want is something in your view that reads more like this

```
<input type="text" name="DynamicDataItem[0].SomeTextField" />
<input type="text" name="DynamicDataItem[0].SomeOtherTextField" />
```

Check out Phil Haack and Scott Hanselman on the topic

[Here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)
and [Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I was having the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037218/httppost-returns-nothing-with-complex-objects-in-mvc3-razor-vb-net) as you and when I was digging I found your page and I think that this can help you too :) :

After Reviewing [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6741129/1055988) gaves me the idea: basically is trying to parse the querystring. You can found it in the controllercontext.httpcontext.

hope that this helps you

Best regards