# Model Binding Collection Using HTTP GET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, query-string, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to model bind a collection of objects in a HTTP GET like so:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Argument { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet("foo")]
public IActionResult GetFoo([FromQuery] IEnumerable<Model> models) { }
```

Firstly, what is the default behaviour in ASP.NET Core in this scenario? The [model binding documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/model-binding.html) is sparse but does say I can use `property_name[index]` syntax.

Secondly, if the default is no good, how would I get a decent looking URL by building some kind of custom model binder that I could reuse as this is a fairly common scenario. For example if I want to bind to the following format:

> ?Foo1=Bar1&Foo2=Bar2

So that the following objects are created:

```
new Model { Argument = "Foo1", Value = "Bar1" }
new Model { Argument = "Foo2", Value = "Bar2" }
```

Comment: @CodeCaster This is for ASP.NET Core. Please look at tags before marking as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much changed [since MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739211/asp-net-mvc-get-list-of-objects-from-query-string/6748667#6748667). Given this model and action method:

```
public class CollectionViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}


public IActionResult Collection([FromQuery] IEnumerable<CollectionViewModel> model)
{

    return View(model);
}
```

You can use the following query strings:

```
?[0].Foo=Baz&[0].Bar=42 // omitting the parameter name
?model[0].Foo=Baz&model[0].Bar=42 // including the parameter name
```

Note that you cannot mix these syntaxes, so `?[0].Foo=Baz&model[1].Foo=Qux` is going to end up with only the first model.

Repetition without indices is not supported by default, so `?model.Foo=Baz&model.Foo=Qux` isn't going to fill your model. If that's what you mean by "decent looking", then you'll need to create a custom model binder.

Comment: What about creating a custom model binder?

Comment: @Muhammad well I guess that's a separate question, in which you should explain what format of the query string you'd like to support and what you have tried.

Comment: Update the question.

Comment: Don't ask two questions in one, that makes it too broad. The first was "how does collection parameter binding work", which this answer answers. If you want to create a custom model binder to support a different format, that's a different question. And again, read [ask] and share your research.