# Is there any performance and memory benefit in re-using value type variables in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, memory

I always try to re-use value type variables because I think it helps the performance of the program by not having to allocate more memory on the stack for a new variable, but I've never confirmed.

Basically my question is, in terms of performance and memory usage, which of the following two blocks of code would perform better?

```
private void Method()
{
     int x;

     for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
     {
          // reusing variable
          x = something...
     }
}
```

vs

```
private void Method()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
     {
          // create new variable
          int x = something...
     }
}
```

Comment: Good compiler will pick the right one depending on it's settings. You should focus on making the code readable.

Comment: This is closed but it should also make very little difference unless your particular method is called many, many times. Even then, the compiler will understand, like Euphoric says, if you store multiple variables but don't access their contents in certain ways, they'll be optimized down to fewer memory anyway.

Comment: I wasn't aware that compilers had some kind of optimization for this this things. I was under the impression that by declaring value-type variables inside a look would make the compiler allocate new memory on the stack for every iteration. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7383090/6198927 explains that the compiler will be aware of that and re-use memory allocated previously or not even create it on the stack. Thank you!