# Why does instantiating variable inline result in faster code?

Tags: c#, .net

I am loading a huge dataset into memory.  The code basically loops through a DataTable and copies values from a DataRow into `int` variables.  For some reason, the variables that I declare inside the loop process almost twice as fast than those that are declared at the top of the method.

Below is the screenshot from Ants Perf Profiler.  As you can, line `siteID = (int) oDR[FIELD_SITE_ID]` is almost twice as slow as the previous line.  Why would that be?

[image]

Comment: have you tried it extracting the same field from the dataset? It could be something tied with the underlying data type and the specific casting for `oDR[FIELD_SITE_ID]`

Comment: Have you tried instantiating `siteID` within the same loop?

Comment: Perhaps looking up `FIELD_SITE_ID` on the row just takes longer than `FIELD_BREAK_ID`.

Comment: Try reorder assignments and tell about your observation.

Comment: There should be no difference, related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535846/is-it-better-to-declare-a-variable-inside-or-outside-a-loop

Comment: You jump to conclusions: You assume that the variable has to do with it. There is no evidence pointing to that.

Comment: @DiskJunky There is no specific casting - these are all ints in both database and c# code.

Comment: @TyrionLannister I can't instantiate siteID in the loop since it's needed down below after the loop.

Comment: @Magnus That's a possibility - I'll try switching to numeric indexer and see what happens.  But then the difference between FIELD_INVENTORY_POD_ID and FIELD_BREAK_ID should be more pronounced.

Comment: Could you post the code of the whole method? Is it possible that `siteID` is closed-over in a lambda (which would mean it's not actually a local variable, but a field in an autogenerated class), or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't it be that `oDR[FIELD_SITE_ID]` is what's slow here? Try assigning it to a variable in the loop and then assign that to the `siteID` variable. If I'm correct you should see that the penalty has moved from your `sideID` assignment to the statement getting the value from `oDR`.

```
int siteIDtmp = (int)oDR[FIELD_SITE_ID];
siteID = siteIDtmp;
```